# What is the correct notation to sum all the first arguments of a set of ground atoms?

Tags: summation, notation

Let $S = \{p(1,a),p(2,b),p(3,c)\}$ be a set of ground dyadic atoms.

What is the correct notation to sum the first argument of all elements in S, i.e. to give the answer 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:
$$\sum_{p(i,j)\in S} i$$

Comment: What is the notation for when the predicate symbols differed? For instance, if S = $\{p(1,a),q(2,b),r(3,c)\}$